# How can I call a function from regular expression matches in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, function

I have a regular expression and I'm wondering if I can use all matches as an argument for a function. For example, let's say that I have a data set

```
Hello heelo hhhheEEeloo eelloooo
```

and a regular expression

```
/[Hh]{1,}[Ee]{1,}[Ll]{1,}[Oo]{1,}/
```

which would match

```
Hello heelo hhhheEEeloo
```

how can I get a javascript function to take in each match as an argument, for example

```
function isHello(arg) {
    if (arg == 'Hello') { return 1 }
    else { return 0}
}
```

Comment: use the `match()` function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`.replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) with a callback

```
"Hello heelo hhhheEEeloo eelloooo".replace(/[Hh]{1,}[Ee]{1,}[Ll]{1,}[Oo]{1,}/g,function(match){
    //Your function code here
    return match;
})
```

Or a more trivial example:

```
var count=0;
"aaaaaaa".replace(/a/g,function(match){
    console.log("I matched another 'a'",count++);
    // just to not replace anything, technically this doesn't matter 
    //since it doesn't operate on the actual string
    return match; 
});
```

#### [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XfeSk/)

Answer (score 1):

```
var string = "Hello heelo hhhheEEeloo eelloooo",
    regex = /[Hh]{1,}[Ee]{1,}[Ll]{1,}[Oo]{1,}/g,
    fn = function(arg){ 
        if (arg == 'Hello')
             return 1;
        return 0
    };
string.match(regex).forEach(fn);
```

Notice the `g` flag added to the regex to match in order to give the desired match.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example using `match()`:

```
var s = "Hello heelo hhhheEEeloo eelloooo";

s.match(/[Hh]{1,}[Ee]{1,}[Ll]{1,}[Oo]{1,}/g).forEach(function(entry) {
    // your function code here, the following is just an example
    if (entry === "Hello")
        console.log("Found Hello!");
    else
        console.log(entry + " is not Hello");
    return;
});
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/wTMuF/